# Run app on Genymotion

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, genymotion

I have installed genymotion onto Android Studio as a plugin. The emulator is now running but when i click run onto the Android Studio. It says that nothing to show on the deployment page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration

If it's already ticked, turn it off and back on again. If that fails restart android studio.